# Can I upload a photo using Facebook SDK with a link in the description?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Can I upload a photo using Facebook SDK with a link in the description? Exactly what it says.
Currently I am able to do that, but without any description at all.
I can add description to the album, but I want to add it to the photo instead.
Respectively add a link to my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yeah you can do it **

```
$facebook = new facebook(array(
       'appId'=>$appId,
       'secret'=>$secret,
       'fileUpload'=>true,
       'cookie'  =>true  

));

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$photo_details = array(
    'message'=> utf8_encode($user_profile['first_name']." ".$user_profile['last_name']." ha usato l'app Perch� \n usi facebook?\n").$link,
);
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath('temp.jpg');

$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$current_album_id.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```